# Unable to Sign-out using Azure AD Authentication on a .Net Core Web App

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, logout

I am unable to signout from a .Net core Web App while using Azure AD to login.

When i try to login using a different email, its just logging in as the previous user who logged in. Its not even asking for password when the new user is trying to login.

I have tried the following approaches but -

```
// Send an OpenID Connect sign-out request.
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

OR

HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

or 

if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(settings.SignInPolicyId);
    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

None of these work on .Net Core.

This code below builds and runs on .net core but it doesnt completely logout the user.

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = clsCommonFunction.GetLoginURL() });
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L13) is the **SignOut** method for **ASP.NET Core**.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SignOut()
{
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action(nameof(SignedOut), "Account", values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
    return SignOut(
        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SignedOut()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // Redirect to home page if the user is authenticated.
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
    }

    return View();
}
```

> Its not even asking for password when the new user is trying to
>   login.

Please clear the browser cache <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.